# Embedding of a finite group in a compact connected Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

How can one embed a finite group $G$ in a compact connected Lie group?
I think if we take a faithful unitary representation of G , that will do the job.But if $G= Z/n$, then what should be the specific candidate for a compact connected Lie group with  minimum dimension ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ embeds into $S^1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Let $Z/n$ embed in $M_n$  , $Z/n \times Z/k$ embed in $M_k$ an $W = M_n \ast (M_k/Z/n) .$ how can I calculate $W^{Z/n}$ and $W^{Z/k} ?$

Comment: I'm not sure what your question in the comment is. For abelian groups, you can show that the minimal dimension of a compact connected group that you can embed into is the minimal number of generators of the group. The idea is that in any embedding of a finite abelian group into a compact connected group, you can actually find a maximal torus that the group embeds into. Hence, any minimal dimension embedding will be a torus. The next thing you should check is that all finite subgroups of $S^{1}$ are cyclic. From this you can proceed by induction on the minimal number of generators.