# Soft Question: intuitive correspondence between manifolds and some family of algebraic structures?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, manifolds, intuition

There is a sense in which $\mathbb{Z}$ "looks like" a line and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ looks like a circle.

For two dimensions / two generators, $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ looks like a plane, $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ like a cylinder, and $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ like a torus.

Is there a way to more formally define this intuitive correspondence? Preferably in such a way that some easily definable subset of $n$-manifolds is one-to-one with some easily definable class of algebraic structures on $n$ generators?

Comment: For me, $\mathbb{Z}^n$ does not "look like" $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is a discrete subset, a lattice.

Comment: There is a correspondence between $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, namely via quasi-isometry. In particular, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an asymptotic cone of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. But such descriptions are too "coarse" for finite groups, so you would lose that part. I'm not really sure it makes sense to call it a correspondence when the finite cyclic groups are involved, because as you've defined it, they all somewhere map to a circle?

Comment: I guess you could also look at the Cayley graph of these groups.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380829/embedding-of-a-finite-group-in-a-compact-connected-lie-group

Comment: Note that $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_3\cong \mathbb Z_6$, so if you want to build a one-to-one mapping that sends $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_3$ to a torus and $\mathbb Z_6$ to a circle, then the mapping has to take advantage of some structure besides the group structure, like a given presentation of the group.